# StrictMode prevents me toggle my style properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

REACTJS learning here, I have very weird issue in REACTJS, when strictmode is disable my code is working but when strictmode is on my code is not working. Any help would be greatly appreaciate. Thankyou! link to codesandbox = https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-problem-6kr0b?file=/src/index.js
I wonder why strictmode would cause such impact to my code. Thank you in advance!

```
(App)
//------------------------------------------
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Todo from './Hi'
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>,
  rootElement
);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

function Texting() {
  const state = {
    list: [{ name: "i am nice", style: { color: "blue" } }]
  };
  const [listt, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, state);
  function reducer(listt, action) {
    switch (action) {
      case "toggle":
        console.log("hi");
        const clone = [...listt.list];
        if (clone[0].style.color === "blue") {
          clone[0].style = { color: "red" };
          return { ...listt, list: clone };
        } else {
          clone[0].style = { color: "blue" };
          return { ...listt, list: clone };
        }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Clone with object</legend>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch("toggle");
          }}
        >
          Click me to toggle color!
        </button>
        <h2 style={listt.list[0].style}>Me</h2>

        {listt.list[0].style.color}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    // <div>
    //   Color = {listt.list.map((x) => x.style.color)}
    //   <button onClick={() => dispatch("toggle")}>toggle!</button>
    //   <h2 style={listt.list[0].style}>
    //    I am awesome
    //   </h2>
    // </div>
  );
}

export default Texting;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `clone[0].style = { color: "red" };` you are overwriting the first index of the `clone` array without creating a new array that's why the state isn't updated in StrictMode. State is only updated when the **reference**
and not the **value** of objects/arrays change.

You should instead be doing something like this:

```js
const clone = { ...listt };

if (clone.list[0].style.color === "blue") {
  clone.list = [{ style: { color: "red" } }];
  return clone;
} else {
  clone.list = [{ style: { color: "blue" } }];
  return clone;
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-problem-forked-5hc47?file=/src/Hi.js:283-372).

Comment: To handle complex state inside of useReducer, I would recommend something like Immer to more easily manipulate the state, otherwise it will get messy and hard to read. A good tutorial here: https://hswolff.com/blog/level-up-usereducer-with-immer/

Comment: @Max Fahl it's out of context, OP is trying to make useReducer work without any external library.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at your code. But from my understanding, the component will render twice in strict mode instead of just once for every change in state or input props. Maybe that is the reason.

One more thing, you should place the reducer function outside the componennt so it won't get created on every render. Should work as you have it right now, but for performance sake it's better to define it outside of the component.

Comment: I see, Thanks for your response, I have another 2 more problems to ask if you dont mind.
1. The console.log code is still able to run more than twice in strictmode
2. When i tried to run the code via VScode, the toggle function did not render even without strict mode . Does VS code implement strict mode by default?

Comment: That was not part of the solution though. I was just taking a guess here. I saw Kent C Dodds explain this a while ago. I don't think StrictMode is ever enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

In strict mode you must fix warnings also. In switch you forgot default.
Check this link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-problem-forked-hkijk

Comment: Thank you for your response. I noticed that in my code, fixing the warning doesn't fix the problems in strict mode. So I assume that the difference that causing two different outputs is ternary operator and if else condition. May I know why my code is still not working even through I have fixed the warning?

Comment: `Style` is getter-only property and assignment to that doesn't affect in strict mode in react.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 0):

`StrictMode` is used to know potential problems at the time of development.
The problem with your code is that you have missed `default` case in switch statement.

Try following :

```
switch (action) {
      case "toggle":
        console.log("hi");
        const clone = [...listt.list];
        if (clone[0].style.color === "blue") {
          clone[0].style = { color: "red" };
          return { ...listt, list: clone };
        } else {
          clone[0].style = { color: "blue" };
          return { ...listt, list: clone };
        }
      default :
        return {...listt}
    }
```